# How to get the Calendly user and organization details which require to call the API

Tags: rest, calendly

I have created a account with Calendly and want to consume the API's. Here is the link for [API's](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/4b402d5ab3edd-calendly-developer)

I have created a token using "Personal Access Token" mechanism provided by Calendly.

If we refer the document, it require some parameter pass to the API like organization, user etc.

I have gone through all the account which I created in Calendly but not able to found these details. Here is the reference where I am expecting it.
[image]

Anyone has any idea how can I get this info in Calendly so I can able to call these API's.

Thanks,

Atul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the way to get the info.

If you have valid account and valid "Personal Access Token" then you can get the info by calling this API of Calendly.

Refer the screeshot:

[image]

This is how you get the details for the user and organization. Then this info you can use to call the API's.

Thanks,

Atul